MCU SysTick infinite loop
During the development of an embedded device, I encountered a one time bug with no interruptions working. It's important to understand that this device usually works fine, and has been for a few years now, without changes of this code part.
After a few investigation, GDB showed me that I was blocked in a while loop, of a delay function :
void delay_ns(uint32_t ns)
{
    SysTick->CTRL = 0;
    SysTick->VAL = 0;

    SysTick->LOAD = 16 * ns; // 16 for 16 MHz
    SysTick->CTRL = SysTick_CTRL_CLKSOURCE_Msk | SysTick_CTRL_ENABLE_Msk;

    while (!(SysTick->CTRL & SysTick_CTRL_COUNTFLAG_Msk)) //BUG HERE
        ;
    SysTick->CTRL = 0;
}

I'm not an MCU dev, and I'm doing my best to understand what's at stake here, but the main informations are :

I'm working with a Cortex-M0+
Here's the definition of Systick
#define SysTick   ((SysTick_Type *) SysTick_BASE  )   /*!< SysTick configuration struct */
Here's SysTick's Type definition

typedef struct
{
  __IOM uint32_t CTRL;               /*!< Offset: 0x000 (R/W)  SysTick Control and Status Register */
  __IOM uint32_t LOAD;               /*!< Offset: 0x004 (R/W)  SysTick Reload Value Register */
  __IOM uint32_t VAL;                /*!< Offset: 0x008 (R/W)  SysTick Current Value Register */
  __IM  uint32_t CALIB;              /*!< Offset: 0x00C (R/ )  SysTick Calibration Register */
} SysTick_Type;

I seem to understand that a error on SysTick is pretty much impossible, and as I do not fully understand MCU's behaviour, I'm wondering where this error comes from.
I'd be glad if you were able to help me in any way !

New compiler or new compiler options? Missing volatile in definition?

How are __IOM, __IM, defined?  Do they include volatile?

Looking at the disassembly of delay_ns might be helpful.  If volatile is missing then there's a good chance that the compiler has optimized out the test in the loop.

volatile is needed somewhere. See: ARM C++ compiler won't compile structure with volatile const member That refers to _IOM needing/using volatile

Is your clock source right? Does the value register even change?

__IOM and __IM both include volatile, and the compiler or its options did not change.
If it's a compiler option that stayed here for a long time, could it be possible that the bug is extremely rare ?

You're not following the initialisation order described in https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0662/b/Cortex-M0--Peripherals/System-timer--SysTick/SysTick-usage-hints-and-tips .  Perhaps you've finally hit a low-probability condition that this sequence avoids?
